# How to give a child class a modified inherited method?

Tags: java, oop

I'm facing a trouble finding the best OOP design solution to the following problem: I have the parent abstract class `Classifier` which includes the abstract method `classify(Instances dataset)`. Two classes extends `Classifier`, namely `NormalClassifier` and `ThresholdClassifier`. Both the children classes implements the `classify(Instances dataset)` method. However, `ThresholdClassifier` requires the `classify(Instances dataset)` method to be of this form `classify(Instances dataset, double threshold)` and can't never work with `classify(Instances dataset)`.

Note that `ThresholdClassifier` can't accept the `threshold` parameter in its constructor and it must have the parameters in the `classify` method.

In this case the child class `ThresholdClassifier` share the same characteristic as the parent but it requires a different method signature. I'm not able to extend the parent class because it would require me to implement the original method signature nor it makes sense not to extend the parent class because it's clearly a `Classifier`. So how would one solve such a design problem in Java OOP? Is there a technical term for this issue?

**Edit 1:**

what I basically did to solve this issue is that I created an interface called `ThresholdBasedClassifier` that contains the method `setThreshold(double threshold)`. Then I made `ThresholdClassifier` implement this method and created an internal field called `threshold`. However, I find this to be an ugly design solution for many reasons, especially that the user could forget that he needs to set *change* or set the threshold before calling `classify(Instances dataset)`

**Edit 2:**

Also the requirements says that there can't be a default value for the `threshold`.

**Edit 3:**

My example above was just an example to a common design problem I'm facing in general. So I'm looking for a general solution not a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple solutions:

1. Make `ThresholdClassifier` extends from `NormalClassifier`.
2. Change `Classifier` to a concrete class (remove abstract).
3. Implement `classify(Instances dataset)` on `ThresholdClassifier` calling the `classify(Instances dataset, double threshold)` with a default `threshold` value.

For example:

```
void classify(Instances dataset) {
    classify(dataset, 10);
}
```

4. Make two empty methods on `Classifier`, so each one overrides the apropriate one:

Code:

```
public abstract class Classifier {
    void classify(Instances dataset) {
    }
    void classify(Instances dataset, double threshold) {
    }
}

public class NormalClassifier extends Classifier {
    void classify(Instances dataset) {
        // Code here
    }
}

public class ThresholdClassifier extends Classifier {
    void classify(Instances dataset, double threshold) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

You can even throw an exception inside Classifier methods. This will enforce the implementation on the child class.

Comment: I want to enforce the design fact that every classifier must implement a `classify` method and by removing abstract you basically eliminated this enforcement.

Comment: `ThresholdClassifier` is not a `NormalClassifier` so it's not logical to extend it.

Comment: and the `threshold` can't have a default value by requirement.

Comment: I might need to implement other children of `Classifier` that has the same design problem as with `ThresholdClassifier` but with a different parameter setting to `classify()`. So just adding a new `classify()` definition to `Classifier` is not design scalable enough. My example above was just an example to a common design problem I'm facing in general.

Comment: Yeah. I think Java can't fit your requirements. You may rethink that. It is so odd, if each child classify method has complete different signatures, they should not be on the same class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

As `ThresholdClassifier` "can't never work with `classify(Instances dataset)`", I think this method shouldn't be declared in `Classifier` abstract class.
You should remove `classify` method from `Classifier` and declare `classify(Instances dataset)` in `NormalClassifier` and `classify(Instances dataset, double threshold)` in `ThresholdClassifier`.

Comment: The idea is that I want to enforce that any Classifier must have a classify method. I want to enforce this by OOP design rather than documentation.

Comment: I see what you want to do, but I don't get the point of enforcing subclasses to have a `classify` method which can accept any number of parameter. In Java, this means that it is not the same method even if they have the same name. Maybe you can show an example of haw you want to call this method.

Answer (score -1):

`ThresholdClassifier` should contain an internal value `double threshold` which allows it to define:

```
private double threshold = DEF_THRESHOLD;

public void setThreshold(final double threshold){
    this.threshold = threshold;
}

@Override
public void classify(Instances dataset){
    this.classify(dataset, threshold);
}

private void classify(Instances dataset, final double threshold){
    // TODO implement this classify method
}
```

**Additional Info**

Are you asking for a general signature? Which I think is worthless because it means that for each different type there will be different interfaces which means you won't get very much reuse out of defining it this way which completely defeats the purpose of using a class hierarchy, interfaces, and abstract classes.  Nevertheless there are such methods in Java.  You would need something like the following:

```
public abstract void classify(final Instances dataset, 
    final Object... options) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Then your `ThresholdClassifier` would look something like this:

```
public ThresholdClassifier extends Classifier{
    @Override
    public void classify(final Instances dataset, 
        final Object... opts) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if(opts.length != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // probably should say something

    try{
        // casts from Double to double automatically
        final double threshold = (Double)opts[0];
        // TODO implement classify method
        //  ...
    }catch(ClassCastException cce){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();// should probably say something
    }
```

You may be able to make the above an abstract class and require a method `void classify(final Instances dataset, final double threshold)` (I'm not totally sure--it may be considered ambiguous since the `double threshold` could be interpreted as either a `double` or a `Double`).

You may also consider making the options explicitly be `String` instead of `Object`.  This at least would allow you to make a general command line driver.